# Up grade to highest level of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

My system is stuck in the Guest mode.  I would like to backup my photos and documents, then down load the latest version so as to start new.  I use Firefox and Thunderbird.  I have been running Ubuntu (14.04 now) since 2008 and have had zero problems until recently.

Comment: Like @Alban stated, you can backup files from a live session (from the Ubuntu installer). On the installation media select "Try Ubuntu" and you can use the file manager to mount your drive and find your files, unless for some reason you have them encrypted (they won't be unless you intentionally did this). From there you can copy the files you need to a USB drive before you install Ubuntu again and erase everything. By the way, you should find most of your files in `/home/your-username`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a guest session loop when I installed 16.04 on top of a 14.04 installation. The problem I encountered was that I used the same /home directory with the same username but I used to have a different desktop environment in the older release, which caused my log-in to fail, only being able to log-in as a Guest.

If you are using 14.04 and in your case, the problem is caused by this same issue the way I managed to solve this is the following:

When in login screen
`Ctrl+Alt+F1`

Now login with your username and password, you don't need to load the Desktop environment so you must not find a problem logging in this way.

Now type and follow instructions:
`sudo useradd "newusername" -s /bin/bash -G sudo -m`

After that make a Unix password for it:
`sudo passwd "newusername"`

This will create the new user account with clean Desktop environment settings and add it to the sudoers group, so you can operate as an administrator from there as usual.

Now do a `sudo reboot` and after your system has restarted you should be able to login to the new user account you just created.

Now open the terminal emulator and
`sudo su`
Now that you operate as root from your new user account, make all your files from the other account be owned by the new one with:
`chown -R newusername: /pathToTheOldUserHomeFolder`

With this done, open Nautilus and procede to copy your files from the old user's folders to the new ones. After you've successfully recovered your files you can delete the old user's Home folder and use your system as usual.

`rm -R /olduserhomepath*`

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the Guest account, go to the upper-right corner of the screen, in the top panel, and select the very last icon on the right. In the menu that drops down, choose `Log out`.

Now you'll be at a login screen where you can log back into your normal account. If the login area shows `Guest`, use the up/down arrows until it changes from `Guest` to your username, then enter your password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you should be back into your account.

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to get to my log in.  Only problem is I can not see my documents and pictures.  I can see them  from the guest page.

Comment: Open the `terminal`, and type `pwd` and tell me the result. Also `ls /home`.